# How to correctly set up docker network to use localhost connection?

Tags: docker, localhost, docker-compose, iptables, docker-network

I have two services. Service A calls service B like this:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:8083/getTest");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

I have the **error**:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Connect to 127.0.0.1:8083 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

This is **docker ps output**:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE        COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2a8eaf08881a        service_A    "./gradlew bootRun"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       service_A
b7436a77e438        service_B    "go-wrapper run"      About an hour ago   Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp   service_B
```

I created **docker network**:

```
docker network create webproxy
```

My **docker-compose.yml** is:

```
version: '3'
services:   
  service_A:
    container_name: service_A
    build: ./service_A
    hostname: service_A
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"

  service_B:
    container_name: service_B
    build: ./service_B
    hostname: service_B
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"     

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: webproxy
```

This is container's **ip addr show eth0**:

```
project$ docker exec -it 2a8eaf08881a ip addr show eth0
68: eth0@if69: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:13:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.19.0.2/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


project$ docker exec -it b7436a77e438 ip addr show eth0
66: eth0@if67: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:13:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.19.0.3/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is **docker network** information:

```
project$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
9fcac7636448        bridge              bridge              local
83a0f3fe901d        host                host                local
215ab1608f91        none                null                local
95909545832d        predictor_default   bridge              local
be19665e791d        webproxy            bridge              local
```

Also I can ping **172.19.0.3** from containers.

How to correctly to communicate between service A and service B?

Comment: Use the service name

Answer (score -3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1125714/tj-biddle has given the working answer:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://service_A:8083/getTest");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Answer (score 7):

In `docker-compose.yml` add `networks` field to each service

```
version: '3'
services:   
  service_A:
    networks:
      - webproxy

  service_B:
    networks:
      - webproxy

networks:
  webproxy:
    driver: bridge
```

Then you can use service names to send requests

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://service_A:8083/getTest");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. docker-compose finished with the error "ERROR: Service "service_B" uses an undefined network "webproxy".

Comment: @Max I thought you already had `webproxy` network. See my updated answer.